# Image Slider Problems with Google Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

I made a site..
And It has an Awesome Bootstrap Slider in it
the Problem with it is...
SLIDER sometimes doesn't loads up ONLY on Google Chrome (PC)
After few refreshes it does.. But on Other Browsers it's all good..
[My site](http://eaglehosted.net/test/index.html)

I tried Re framing CSS and Adding some Liberarys etc, still doesnt work

Comment: Funny thing is that on Google Chrome it always load, it doesn't load at 1st time on Firefox and Opera.
Are you sure you meant that it doesn't load on Google Chrome?

Comment: You have two errors.  You're mixing up Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 classes.  You seem to have your styles in your body not your head tags.  You don't have a viewport tag.  And that's just the stuff I noticed in a quick look.  I think the problem is with the slidestrap plugin that you're using.  I recommend you revisit the documentation for using that plugin with Bootstrap 3.  Just FYI, I had problems loading your site on Firefox and Chrome.